# How to Get Where 'Column + 7 Days' >= NOW in PHP

Tags: php, sql

I have a problem. Maybe this question is very stupid, but I've been searching everywhere and not getting what I want.
I will immediately delete my post, if I get the answer.

I've a table like this:

```
 ID |     Title  |   Date 
-----------------------------
  1 |     AAA    | 2019-03-25
  2 |     BBB    | 2019-03-21
  3 |     CCC    | 2019-03-23
```

I've tried this:

```
function get_all() {
    $plusdays = strtotime('+7 day');
    $now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $this->datatables->select('*');
    $this->datatables->from('atable');
    $this->datatables->where('crt_date + INTERVAL 7 day >=', $now);
    return $this->datatables->generate();
}
```

How I can show table like this:

```
 ID |     Title  |   Date 
-----------------------------
  2 |     BBB    | 2019-03-21
```

So I want to show data created on a certain date and expire if more than 7 days after the data was created. Or are there other ideas? 
do I have to add the expired date column?
Thanks

Comment: **Do NOT immediately delete your question upon a receiving an answer.** That's not how StackOverflow works. Deleting your question deprives a person with a similar (or the same!) question as you from getting an answer in the future.

Comment: What database are you using? mysql? oracle? sql-server?

Comment: Ok, I'll not delete this post immediately. @Isaiah

Comment: I using database mysql @catcon

Comment: Why not calculate `now() - 7 days` as a single constant expression,  and use that instead of potentially adding 7 days to millions of dates ? `date+7>=now` is equivalent to `date>=now-7`

Comment: Ok, i'll try in the future. Thank you! @CaiusJard

Answer (score 0):

Here's an SQL query that should work (and no, it's not necessarily the most elegant one):

```
SELECT *
FROM atable
WHERE (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date)) >= (60 * 60 * 24 * 7);
```

I presume you can translate that appropriately to your PHP code. Basically, I'm getting the difference in seconds between now() and the stored date then I'm seeing if the difference is greater than or equal to seven days.

Comment: Ok, i'll try in the future. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I decided to add one more column is exp_date for easier use in the future.
Code like this:

```
$date = time();
$date_exp = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+7 day', $date));
```

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

> Tip Don't use function or eval in column at where (performance problem)

In this case you must subtract $now by 7 day and

```
$this->datatables->where('crt_date >=', $theDateBefore7Day);
```